# How to control display of password prompt based on HTTP_USER_AGENT in apache?

Tags: apache, kerberos

I've Kerberos authentication enabled in my website using Apache 2.4 and have the "KrbMethodK5Passwd" directive set to off.
So, users get logged in automatically into the site and don't see the password prompt.

However, for security reasons we need the password prompt to appear only on mobile devices and so I'm trying to set the KrbMethodK5Passwd value to on based on HTTP_USER_AGENT

I've tried writing  directive, but couldn't get it to work

Comment: "for security reasons we need the password prompt to appear only on mobile devices" - do you mean that having the password prompt appear on anything other than mobile devices is a risk, or that using anything else on mobile devices is a risk? Also, are you using apache as a proxy to a web application, or just serving static files? If using an app, I'd suggest handling your security in that with sessions, and then just use kerberos to get the session cookie. That way it's easy to re-direct to a custom login screen if kerberos fails for any reason (including not being supported on mobile).

Comment: Having the password prompt on anything other than mobile device is not expected behavior since users expect to be logged in via SSO in their browser. The application I'm talking about is Drupal CMS